# Error connecting to SLiM server on localhost:8080

Tags: java, git, unit-testing, fitnesse-slim

I am running a test case using java  & fitnesse...

while Clicking on the "Test" button from below image,

[image: page]

It showing error as follows:

```
   Standard Error:
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ":build/classes://////var/www/git/vodaware/java/Build:/root/leadout-tests///////var/www/git/vodaware/java/supportLibs/mockito-all-1/9/5/jar:/root/leadout-tests///////var/www/git/vodaware/java/supportLibs/jsp-api/jar:/root/leadout-tests///////var/www/git/vodaware/java/supportLibs/testng-6/8/7/jar:/root/leadout-tests///////var/www/git/vodaware/java/supportLibs/servlet-api/jar:/root/leadout-tests///////var/www/git/vodaware/java/supportLibs/jcip-annotations-1/0/jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ":build.classes:......var.www.git.vodaware.java.Build:.root.leadout-tests.......var.www.git.vodaware.java.supportLibs.mockito-all-1.9.5.jar:.root.leadout-tests.......var.www.git.vodaware.java.supportLibs.jsp-api.jar:.root.leadout-tests.......var.www.git.vodaware.java.supportLibs.testng-6.8.7.jar:.root.leadout-tests.......var.www.git.vodaware.java.supportLibs.servlet-api.jar:.root.leadout-tests.......var.www.git.vodaware.java.supportLibs.jcip-annotations-1.0.jar
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
Could not find the main class: ":build/classes:../../var/www/git/vodaware.java/Build:/root/leadout-tests/../../var/www/git/vodaware.java/supportLibs/mockito-all-1.9.5.jar:/root/leadout-tests/../../var/www/git/vodaware.java/supportLibs/jsp-api.jar:/root/leadout-tests/../../var/www/git/vodaware.java/supportLibs/testng-6.8.7.jar:/root/leadout-tests/../../var/www/git/vodaware.java/supportLibs/servlet-api.jar:/root/leadout-tests/../../var/www/git/vodaware.java/supportLibs/jcip-annotations-1.0.jar. Program will exit.
```

What is the cause of this logs? Please anyone help me.

Comment: Looks like either a fitnesse setup problem or a bug in fitnesse itself

Comment: @fge I started finesse using http://i.stack.imgur.com/zuTIh.jpg  . But once error displayed on Ui, at the same time it shows error like `error registered in test system [Error connecting to SLiM server on localhost:8086]`  Any help?

Comment: @fge Please help me , any-other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, the program is not able to find the java class. You need to make sure the 
class path is set properly and also make sure the package location is set properly.

Ex:

classpath: foo/bar/

package: jane/doe.class

See to it that you mention the package hierarchy properly while setting it in the fitnesse column.

Hope this helps.